# Pass data from model through hidden field or default form values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a "fitness" tracker for users to enter things like "weight, Mile Time". I'm very novice with RoR and I'm trying to write my form so that if a user makes a "New" stats post, it will default the last data from the database rather than just empty values if they don't include all new values. let me elaborate: If a user clicks "New" they can enter their weight and mile time. If they don't include both, I get an empty value in my table. I believe this can be accomplished though hidden_fields but I'm unsure how to use them - even after reading documentation.

```
    <% @stats.each do |stat| %>
            <table class="table table-sm">
              <thead>
                <th scope="col">Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
    
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= stat.mile %></td>
                  <td><%= stat.created_at.strftime("#{stat.created_at.day.ordinalize} %B %Y") %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stat_path(stat), class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm" %>
                   <%= link_to 'Delete', stat, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          <% end %>
<% @stats.each do |stat| %>
        <table class="table table-sm">
          <thead>
            <th scope="col">Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><%= stat.weight %></td>
              <td><%= stat.created_at.strftime("#{stat.created_at.day.ordinalize} %B %Y") %></td>
              <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stat_path(stat), class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm" %>
               <%= link_to 'Delete', stat, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      <% end %>
```

Here is my very basic form for new stats:

```
    <%= form_with(model: stat) do |form| %>
  <% if stat.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(stat.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this stat from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% stat.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :mile %>
    <%= form.text_field :mile %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :weight %>
    <%= form.text_field :weight %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Added stats_controller

```
**stats_controller.rb**
class StatsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_stat, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /stats
  def index
    @stats = current_user.stats.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
  end

  # GET /stats/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /stats/new
  def new
    @stat = current_user.stats.new
  end

  # GET /stats/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /stats
  def create
    @stat = current_user.stats.new(stat_params)

    if @stat.save
      redirect_to @stat, notice: 'Stat was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /stats/1
  def update
    if @stat.update(stat_params)
      redirect_to @stat, notice: 'Stat was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /stats/1
  def destroy
    @stat.destroy
    redirect_to stats_url, notice: 'Stat was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_stat
      @stat = Stat.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def stat_params
      params.require(:stat).permit(:user_id, :mile, :weight, :waist, :hips, :leftleg, :rightleg, :leftarm, :rightarm, :chest,:bust,:wallsit, :plank, :pushup, :burpee, :situp, :jumpsquat)
    end
end
```

Comment: This is not really what hidden fields are used for. Also it seems it should be more obvious that you are using default values, so maybe initialize the form with them or have a button so the user can load the latest values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do this in your controller code...

since you didn't include controller code, you can also do this in your view:

```
<% 
  last_stat = current_user.stats.where.not(weight: nil).last
  stat.weight = last_stat.weight if last_stat
  stat.mile = last_stat.mile if last_stat
%>

<%= form_with(model: stat) do |form| %>
# ...
```

Inside your form inputs, you can also add `required: true` so the user is required to submit them...

Comment: This little piece of code is exactly what I was looking for. I changed "user" to current_user and now it is working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: The issue Im having with this is that if I have a new user access this form, the user gets an error as the last data will be nil. I'm thinking a nested hidden field in the sign up form to pre-populate that model would be the best bet to fix this?

Comment: @BjPetrie i've updated my code-sample. Add `if last_state`.